# getting table info(exist/not) from cursor

Tags: android

in my activity ineed to check whether the table exist or not for that im using

```
 Cursor cursor = marksdb.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='"+classt+"'", null);
```

im getting 1 if table exist 0 otherwise
for that i need check value in cursor for that im using

```
if(cursor.getCount()==1){
        // get values from cursor here
         callclasstb();
        }
     else{
         tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        subjectet.setEnabled(false);
        markset.setEnabled(false);
        markssp.setEnabled(false);
     }
```

but in all cases im getting value 1 because getcout() returns a value 1 r 0 and

```
callclasstb();
```

is not executing what condition i need to write in if{....} to make it execute

Comment: have you run the query from the shell and verified it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.getCount()` in your case will always return 1 (the number of "rows" in your resultset). you need to figure out what was returned via the cursor.

```
     Cursor cursor = marksdb.rawQuery(...);
     cursor.moveToFirst(); // first "row"
     int nTableExists = cursor.getInt(0);
     cursor.close();

     if (nTableExists) { // != 0
        ...do something...
     }
```